# Mongoose - group, count and return 0 when nothing found in collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections in my mongoDB database - `users` and `connections`.
Each `connection` has field `user` which contains `_id` of an `user` stored in `users` collection.

I need to find total number of connections per user, and if user has no connections, it should show 0 as his total.

Also to find number of connections whose `date` field doesn't equal `''` per user.

I wrote this code which retuns total number of connections per user, but only for users which have at least one connection, users without connections don't show up at all...

```
Connection.aggregate(
                [
                    {
                        $group: {
                            _id: "$user",
                            total: { $sum: 1 },
                            withDate: { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $ne: ["$date", ""] }, then: 1, else: 0 } } }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: "users",
                            localField: "_id",
                            foreignField: "_id",
                            as: "users"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $unwind: "$users"
                    },
                    {
                        $project: {
                            Email: "$users.local.email",
                            "Last Edit": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$users.local.lastConnectionEdit" } },
                            "Total Connections": "$total",
                            "Connections With Date": "$withDate"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                function(err, dashboardData) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.status(500).end({ error: "Error fetching stats from database" });
                    } else {
                        let csv = json2csv(dashboardData);

                        res.attachment("stats.csv");
                        res.status(200).send(csv);
                    }
                }
            );
```

Connection schema:

```
    active:Boolean,
    info: {
        name: String,
        profileImg: String,
        bio: String
    },
    connURL:String,
    handle:String,
    notes: String,
    date: String,
    value: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    tags: [String],
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
```

User schema:

```
local: {
        email: String,
        password: String,
        admin: Boolean,
        snoozeAmount: Number,
        snoozeInterval: String,
        emailIntervalWeeks: Number,
        emailIntervalDay: Number,
        isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        verifyToken: String,
        passwordResetToken: String,
        lastConnectionEdit: Date
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "connections",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "user",
    "as": "connections"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "total": { "$size": "$connections" },
    "withDate": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$connections",
        "initialValue": 0,
        "in": {
          "$add": [
            "$$value",
            { "$sum": {
              "$cond": { "if": { "$ne": [ "$$this.date", "" ] }, "then": 1, "else": 0 }
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, this now returns all users and total number of connections even if they have 0! . But I'm not sure how to get the `withDate` from my original post working within your code? It should calculate the number of connections per user whose `date` field isn't equal to `''`

Comment: can you post your sample collection ? and what is your mongodb version?

Comment: Too many fields, but what's important is that `Connection` has fields `user` (contains `_id` from `User` collection) and `date`. Your code returns all users and their total number of connections (even if they have none) just like it should, I just need to check for each of these users how many of their connections have `date` field NOT set to empty string and return it as a `withDate` field.

MongoDB is 3.4.14

Comment: Yes I understood but if you post your sample data then I can easily explain you a better solution and precise way

Comment: OK, I've updated OP with schemas for `Connection` and `User` if it helps.

Comment: No it's not what I need :( 
It returns like this:
`{connections: [{"date":"2018-08-21","withDate":"2018-08-21"},{"date":"","withDate":""},{"date":"2018-08-05","withDate":"2018-08-05"}]
}`

In simple words, output just needs to contain total connections per user, and total connections with date NOT set to empty string per user, but to export also users which don't have any connections related to them.

Just like my code in OP does, its only problem was that it didn't export users who don't have connections related to them (they should export with total = 0, withDate = 0).

Comment: Example output : 
[{email: 'johnsmith@gmail.com',
total: 50,
withDate:22},
{email: 'I_have_no_connections@gmail.com',
total: 0,
withDate:0}]

Comment: Updated have a look

Comment: Everything's fine except withDate field, it returns only 1 or 0 as value for all users (although many of them have 100s of connections with date). Seems like $sum in $reduce isn't correct?

Comment: I found a fix:
`$sum: [
           "$$value",
           {
            $cond: {
             if: {
              $ne: ["$$this.date", ""]
             },
             then: 1,
             else: 0
            }
           }
          ]`

Comment: Please update your answer with this piece of code and I'll accept it! Many thanks!

Comment: the code I pasted in last comment seems simpler and it works, does your code have some advances over it? I see that you're expert at this, I'd just like to hear your opinion on it :)